# Pipe breaking with return

Tags: python, python-2.7

newbie question here;

I have the two following functions - the first, 'read_fq_entry', reads lines from a subprocess.Popen (which system calls zcat and pipes it) and returns four lines at a time as a list.

The second, 'stream_fq', takes returned output from the first and for the moment prints it. (eventually I will be sampling random sets of lines and writing them to files.

The problem is that the return in the first function breaks the pipe - any idea on how not to do this??

```
 def read_fq_entry( process ):

        while ( True ):
            name   = process.stdout.readline()       
            seq    = process.stdout.readline()
            strand = process.stdout.readline()
            qual   = process.stdout.readline()

            if ( not name or name == '') :
                return []

            return [name, seq, strand, qual]


 def stream_fq(infile1, infile2, Nr_of_reads):


        proc1 = subprocess.Popen("zcat " + infile1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        proc2 = subprocess.Popen("zcat " + infile2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

        while ( True ):

            fq_1_entry = read_fq_entry(proc1)
            fq_2_entry = read_fq_entry(proc2)
            print fq_1_entry
            print fq_2_entry
```

Comment: This probably isn't related to your problem, but `not name or name == ''` is redundant because `not name` evaluates to True when `name` is the empty string. Shortening it to `if not name:` would have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - good tip

Comment: Write ```stream_fq``` as a [coroutine](http://wla.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa11/lectures/streams.html#coroutines) and ```send``` lines to it. If I was at my desk I'd answer with an example, hopefully that will get you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `return [name, seq, strand, qual]` is inside the `while True:` loop.  You should move it up one level, ***or*** perhaps change the `return` statement into a `yield` statement instead.

Comment: That won't help.  OP wants a generator, but that's a major rewrite.

Comment: Define generator - can rewrite if needed, looking for the best possible solutions.